# Computes a geometric intersection of the input features and update the feature from input feature class accordingly in esri srcgis

Tags: javascript, python, arcgis

I would like to update the field in the input  feature class after I identify the intersection/ overlap  between feature from other feature class .

I have tried to use identify gp and I couldn't move further after identifying the intersection.

i am looking to populate field in the input feature class if it intersect with the other input.

#### Update

Here's the code

```
// Replace a layer/table view name with a path to a dataset 
// (which can be a layer file) or create the layer/table 
// view within the script # The following inputs are layers or 
// table views:"TXDC_OWN_D15_PROJ_GIS_LOCN_LN","AGO_nhs"

arcpy
 .SelectLayerByLocation_management(
   in_layer="TXDC_OWN_D15_PROJ_GIS_LOCN_LN", 
   overlap_type="WITHIN", 
   select_features="AGO_nhs", 
   search_distance="", 
   selection_type="NEW_SELECTION", 
   invert_spatial_relationship="NOT_INVERT"
)
```

Comment: If you show some code am sure you will get help faster

Comment: Please look here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: hi @FemiOni when I use the above code it is not returning any record if I use manual selection tool inside arcmap it is returning the expected result

Comment: I am not an expert with arcpy but here is a link that might help https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/171532

Comment: also this http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/select-layer-by-location.htm